# Gravar último login por meio do mysql e exibir quem está online

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, que na verdade já está funcionando. Mas há algo que já tentei de mil maneiras mas ainda não consigo implementar. Preciso gravar em uma tabela já existente no banco as datas/horários de login e logout de cada usuário. E depois exibir se esse usuário ainda está online ou não...

Abaixo posto a tabela de meu BD e as páginas de login e logout:

Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_clientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sobrenome` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Inativo',
  `foto` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mast_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data_alteracao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `city` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `idade` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Página de login:

```php
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

$message = '';
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: welcome.php");
  exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
include('chat/database_connection.php');
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM tab_clientes WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
                     
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tutto L'amore | Login</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/icon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
      <!--<a href="/Membros/index.php">Membros</a>-->
      <a href="/contatos">Contato</a>
      <a href="register.php">Cadastrar</a>
      <a href="#home" style="width: 10%"><img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 80px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: -3px"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
        
        <div class="underLine"></div>
        
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
    </script>    
        
        <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper" style="width: 400px; margin: auto">
            <h2>Entrar</h2>
            <p><h5>Por favor para logar preencha com seus dados.</h5></p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label><h6 style="font-weight: bold;">Nome de usuário</6></label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label><h6 style="font-weight: bold;">Senha</h6></label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar">
                </div>
                <p><h5>Não tem uma conta? <a href="register.php">Cadastre-se agora</a>.</5></p>
            </form>
        </div>    
     </div>    
    <?php
    
    include 'includes/footer.php';
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Página de logout:

```php
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
    
// Unset all of the session variables
$_SESSION = array();
    
// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();
    
// Redirect to login page
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: seria mais fácil e prático criar uma tabela para guardar todos os registros dos clientes, armazenando a data e hora de acesso e fazer consultas no banco para verificar o visto por último dele, ou seja, a hora que ele saiu do sistema e exibir se ele está online no momento ou não.

Comment: Sim Leo, seu comentário parece estar bem próximo de minha pergunta. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Você poderia me dar algum exemplo prático?

Comment: depende no nível de precisão do "quem está online" usando a sessão do php junto com data/hora de acesso vai dar um valor aproximado, para obter o valor exato precisa de uma comunicação em tempo real, com socket, por exemplo

Answer (score -2):

Vai ter que fazer com cookies. Set quando ele logar e ao mesmo tempo o insert no banco e quando ele sair zera os dados do cookie, no momento que esse cookie for alterado faz um delete na tabela.

Assim vc seta:
setcookie("CookieTeste", $value);

Assim vc limpa:

function clearcookie( $inKey ) {
clearpieces( $inKey , 1 );
setcookie( $inKey , '' , time()-3600 , '/' , '' , 0 );
unset( $_COOKIE[$inKey] );
}

Comment: Oi, obrigada por ter respondido, eu ainda não tenho experiência com cookies e, nem concebo a ideia de como começar usá-los. Por favor, me dê alguns exemplos para eu ter uma ideia mais sólida. Posso usar nos códigos das páginas que eu postei? Uso como se fosse uma função e chamo ela?

Comment: O Celke explica muito bem nesse post dele : https://celke.com.br/artigo/como-criar-cookies-em-php

Comment: Olá, assisti ao vídeo do Celke, e criar cookies realmente é muito fácil. Agora estou buscando uma maneira de inserir os dados de login, como data e horário em uma tabela no BD. Mas sua diga mostrou-me o caminho. Obrigada.